# Last inserted id from SQLite in FireFox add-on

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon, xpcom

im writing addon for firefox and use SQLite trough XPCOM.

Can anyone explain how to get last inserted id from autoincrement column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`lastInsertRowId` on the connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mozIStorageConnection#Attributes).  However, you [should avoid using synchronous statement execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Storage#Synchronously), which means you cannot rely on that property.  You'll have to run another SQL query to get that value.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

`SELECT last_insert_rowid();`